# Text file batch word replacement using Python and Notepad++ Unicode format

Tags: python, notepad++

The problem I am facing is for Unicode text file.Notepad++ plugin>python script.
Below code perfectly works and replace the words contains the wordlist.txt. Only it works for English. Non ASCII it is unable to search. I tried `With open('C:\Users\Desktop\wordlist.txt') as f:` --> `with io.open('C:\Users\Desktop\wordlist.txt', encoding='utf-8') as f:` but notepad++ not performing for Unicode words text file.
Now i need help how to pass unicode string for search. in the below code. Else please help with python code for batch whole word replace in `A.text` file using "word list find and replace with delimiter in `B.Text` file".

```
With open('C:\Users\Desktop\wordlist.txt') as f:
    for l in f:
        s = l.split()
        editor.rereplace(r'\b' + s[0] + r'\b', s[1])
```

Comment: Could you give some examples from `wordlist.tx` (and text to be modified)  that don't work?

Comment: @Toto Wordlist.txt  [(https://drive.google.com/file/d/1Y3Hy6NqI-OJvchU0yw0JXzDbTLBd729n/view?usp=sharing)] , Texttobemodified.txt (https://drive.google.com/file/d/15PCH5z_brtlmpjdDhoh84UqCBSglbGxj/view?usp=sharing)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Do not use word boundary `\b` that cause problem with utf8 characters. Use instead lookaround:

```
import re

with open('D:\\temp\\wordlist.txt') as f:
    for l in f:
        s = l.split()
        editor.rereplace(r'(?<!\S)' + s[0] + r'(?!\S)', '\t' + s[1])
```

Where:

- `(?<!\S)` is a negative lookbehind that make sure with haven't a NON space before the word to be modified
- `(?!\S)`  is a negative lookahead that make sure with haven't a NON space after the word to be modified

With your 2 sample files, I got:

```
    मारुती
नामशिवाया 
    जयश्रीराम 
जयश्रीराम
```

- Note: I've added tabulation before the modified words for redability, remove it for your application.

**Screenshot:**

[image]

Comment: ,Thanks a Lot. You are Really saved me a lot of days. I am struggling this for the last few days. Thanks again. And one more help pls in wordlist.txt is it possible to have multiple words as one, example -Hello world (F)-----Good Morning(R). Have a Great Day!

Comment: @OhmDios: Sure, you may have multiple words, but in your case, you'll have a problem with the `s = l.split()` line because it will split in more than 2 array elements. How to split `blah blah blah`? `blah blah` & `blah` or `blah` & `blah blah`?

Comment: Yes, instead of line can we use match group of words and in wordlist.txt instead of space some special characters like (:).For example: - blah blah blah(F) to be replaced --- Lorem Ex Lorem(R)